# Error with the measure button on the vertical toolbar with Autodesk platform services

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk, autodesk-bim360

The measure button of Autodesk Platform Services (forge viewer) does not work for me. When the toolbar is vertical and I click on the button, it does nothing. When it is horizontal there is no problem. The rest of the buttons work fine.

I would like to find a solution to be able to position the tool vertically with the measure button working.

[image: Measure button]

I have also verified that it does not work horizontally when we add it to another toolbar

Answer (score 0):

The **Viewer** does actually support **vertical** toolbars - see `function ToolBar(id, options)` in [viewer3D.js](https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/viewer3D.js) that has option `alignVertically`, and if that's true, it simply adds class `adsk-toolbar-vertical` to it.

One of the simplest ways to make the toolbar vertical is to create an extension that adds the same class to the toolbar once it has been created:

```
class VerticalToolbarExtension extends Autodesk.Viewing.Extension {
  onToolbarCreated(toolbar) {
    toolbar.addClass("adsk-toolbar-vertical");
  }
}
Autodesk.Viewing.theExtensionManager.registerExtension('VerticalToolbarExtension', VerticalToolbarExtension);
let viewerDiv = document.getElementById('MyViewerDiv');
viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D(viewerDiv,{extensions: ["VerticalToolbarExtension"]});

viewer.start();

viewer.loadDocumentNode(doc, viewables[0]);
```

[image]

I assume you are having issues because you are recreating the toolbar? In which case you would need to make sure that everything is as the `Measure` tool expects it. You can check what it's trying to do when you click the `Measure` button by looking at the `MeasureExtension.prototype.enterMeasurementMode` function in [Measure.js](https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/extensions/Measure/Measure.js)